# DataAnnotation to display month name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dataformat, displayformat

How to display the full month name and year in DataFormatString?(November-2014)

I tried using this DataAnnotation,but it does not give me the desired o/p:

```
 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="0:MMMM-yyyy")]
```

Comment: What this give you as an output? Your formats are okey.

Comment: Does not give any output,just displays 0:MMMM-yyyy this

Comment: Your example is missing some code. What does the property look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know it makes a difference or not but how about;

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MMMM-yyyy}")]
```

From [`DisplayFormatAttribute.DataFormatString` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.dataformatstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The formatting string can be any literal string and usually includes a
>   placeholder for the field's value. For example, in the formatting
>   string "Item Value: {0}", the field's value is substituted for the {0}
>   placeholder when the string is displayed in the DynamicField object.
>   The remainder of the formatting string is displayed as literal text.
>
> **If the formatting string does not include a placeholder, the field's
>   value from the data source is not included in the final display text.**

Answer (score 2):

You're missing brackets:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:MMMM-yyyy}")]
```